# What doesn vintage mean in "1980-vintage person"?

Tags: word-usage

What does *vintage* mean in "1980-vintage person"?
I lookup up in dictionary, but still cannot find one meaning or usage that fits here.

Comment: I think we need more context. My first impression was that it could be a person who is interested in vintage items specifically from the 1980s.

Comment: [*vintage*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vintage): "5b. A year or period of origin: *a car of 1942 vintage*" or [*vintage*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vintage): "5. *informal* a group of people or objects of the same period ⇒ *a fashion of last season's vintage*. More context needed.

Comment: @user3169, yes, this is exactly the explanation that fits here.

Comment: A 1980 vintage Eps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is probably a noun usage of [vintage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vintage), meaning the year that a wine was made. For example, the following sentence refers to wine produced in 1983.

> The 1983 vintage was one of the best

If taken literally, a **1980-vintage person** is therefore somebody that was born in 1980, however it might also be used to refer to somebody born in approximately 1980, or even in the 1980's.